# PHP and Android: java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am getting error when I test below code in Android phone:

```
org.json.JSONException: 
    Value <!-- of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

My PHP Code as follows: I have used prepare statement

```
<?php

 define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
 require_once(__ROOT__.'/public_html/Config.php');

 // Connecting to mysql database
 $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

 // json response array
 $response = array();

 if (isset($_POST['treecondition'])) {

  // receiving the post params

 $treecondition = $_POST['treecondition'];

 // get the tree details for google map marker

   if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT treeid, treelatitude, treelongitude FROM tree WHERE treecondition = ?")){

  $stmt->bind_param("s", $treecondition);

  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->store_result();

  $stmt->bind_result($treeid, $treelatitude, $treelongitude);

  if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

  while($tree = $stmt->fetch()) {

   $response['treeid'] = $treeid;
   $response['treelatitude'] = $treelatitude;
   $response['treelongitude'] = $treelongitude;

   echo json_encode($response);
    }  
    }

   } else {
     // user is not found with the credentials
     $response["error"] = TRUE;
     $response["error_msg"] = "Tree list view credentials are wrong.  Please try again!";
     echo json_encode($response);
      }
    $mysqli->close();
     }
```

My Android volley code as follows: Used Jsonarray

```
 public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Location Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();



            try {


                JSONArray jTreeList = new JSONArray(response);
                // boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

                // Check for error node in json
                for (int i = 0; i < jTreeList.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject location = jTreeList.getJSONObject(i);


                    String treeid = location.getString("treeid");
                  //  String treespecies = location.getString("treespecies");
                    Double treelatitude = location.getDouble("treelatitude");
                    Double treelongitude = location.getDouble("treelongitude");

                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(treelatitude, treelongitude);

                    list.add(new LatLng(treelatitude, treelongitude));

                    // Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs of the police stations.
                    HeatmapTileProvider provider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder().data(list).build();
                    // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
                    mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(provider));
                    // Moving CameraPosition to last clicked position
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

                    // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position is clicked
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(3));

                }

                // Launch
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("search", search);



            return params;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

Please look of my error after the output of program

```
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow D/ClusterMapFragment﹕ Location Response:
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕   org.json.JSONException: Value <!-- of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at com.example.bharat.plantnow.Maps.ClusterMapFragment$2.onResponse(ClusterMapFragment.java:143)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at com.example.bharat.plantnow.Maps.ClusterMapFragment$2.onResponse(ClusterMapFragment.java:131)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-20 14:32:38.450  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
11-20 14:32:38.451  23138-23138/com.example.bharat.plantnow W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: Please update your logcate

Comment: Check your received JSON, probably it have an incorrect format.

Comment: I have added logcate error. Pl see

Comment: @Rami Can you please which line is incorrect!

Comment: @Bharat Check if your `response` String have a **valid JSON format**.

Comment: if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT treeid, treelatitude, treelongitude FROM tree WHERE treecondition = ?")){

 $stmt->bind_param("s", $treecondition);
  $stmt->execute(); $stmt->store_result();

      
$treeItem = array();
  if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
     while($tree = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $treeItem["treeid"] = $tree['treeid'];
            $treeItem["treelatitude"] = $tree['treelatitude'];
            $treeItem["treelongitude"] = $tree['treelongitude'];
            $response[] = $treeItem;
  }      echo json_encode($response);      [{"treeid":null,"treelatitude":null,"treelongitude":null}]

Comment: Gettitng null values:[{"treeid":null,"treelatitude":null,"treelongitude":null}]

Answer (score 0):

The Json response you receive is not formatted as JSON it contains invalid character  `'<!--'`   thats why your jsonparser throw an Jsonexception.

Try to save your php file in cp1252 Encoding

1. Open your php file in Eclipse
2. Edit> Set Encoding then set to cp1252
3. save